# Evaluate the product $\operatorname{tr}(AB)\operatorname{tr}(CB^{-1})$

Tags: matrices, trace, positive-definite

Let $A,C$ be given positive semidefinite matrices, $B$ be an arbitrary positive definite matrix. How can I estimate the value of $\DeclareMathOperator{tr}{tr}\tr(AB)\tr(CB^{-1})$ ? Is that true $\tr(AB)\tr(CB^{-1}) \geq \tr(AC)$ ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $\operatorname{tr}(AB)\operatorname{tr}(CB^{-1})\ge\operatorname{tr}(AC)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\operatorname{tr}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2})\operatorname{tr}(B^{-1/2}CB^{-1/2})\ge\operatorname{tr}(B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}B^{-1/2}CB^{-1/2}),\tag{1}
$$
which boils down to
$$
\operatorname{tr}(X)\operatorname{tr}(Y)\ge\operatorname{tr}(XY)\tag{2}
$$
for positive semidefinite matrices $X$ and $Y$. Rewrite $(2)$ as $\|X^{1/2}\|_F^2\|Y^{1/2}\|_F^2\ge\|X^{1/2}Y^{1/2}\|_F^2$, we see that it always holds because Frobenius norm is submultiplicative.